# viewing email logs from last 24 hours only

Tags: linux, email, ssh, exim

I am in the process of writing a ssh command to process certain email log entries with awk into a nice readable format. This script is to be run only on entries to /var/log/exim_mainlog that are from the last 24 hours. I am not very familiar with time searching options. Any suggestions on the best way to grep the email logs for only entries that are dated in the last 24 hours? preferably a grep option or something similar. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: How are the logs formatted?

Comment: `find` and its time options will probably come in handy here.

Comment: The logs differ in formatting, but I am pulling every log containing "No Such User Here" within the last 24 hours. the date is formatted like so:

2012-12-23 00:05:07

Comment: Can find be used on logs files? I thought it wouldn't work because ti finds files not text althoughugh Im sure I could be mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [sawmill](http://www.sawmill.net/) does what you want? It parses [exim](http://www.exim.org) mail logs and allows you to filter by time. Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: although this would be helpful, I actually have to write the script so using some software is out of the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **exiqgrep** command which may already be installed on your system.

Comment: I do have exigrep installed, but I am not so sure if it can be used to manipulate the exim_mainlog the way I want to. essentially I am looking to grab all logs with "No Such User Here" in them within the last 24 hours, and then format that output using awk